# How to install ipfw / DummyNet on Ubuntu 10.10?

Tags: ubuntu, traffic-shaping, ipfw

There seems to be a man page an ipfw but I can't find what package I have to install to use ipfw / DummyNet. Any hints?

Comment: Are you needing ipfw/dummynet specifically, or is there a requirement that can be fulfilled with a different software package or packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ipfw is the freebsd firewall package.

Dummynet however is available for Linux and must be usable somehow from iptables. I haven't yet found a tutorial on how to use it with linux.  I'm sure it'll exist somewhere.

Looks like you have to compile it yourself.

See [README](http://info.iet.unipi.it/~luigi/dummynet/README) file that comes with the dummynet source.

Comment: Hm, it doesn't work on Ubuntu 10.10. insmod ./dummynet2/ipfw_mod.ko complains about an incompatible module.

Comment: You might need to ensure you have an identical kernel version to the one listed on the dummynet homepage.